# Creating a button in Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, python, typescript, sharepoint, spfx

I'm working for an IT comapny and I got a task that I have to finish in short time.

Basically I have to create a button on a sharepoint site, this button needs to fetch the users Credentials (name and email) and paste them into an excel sheet on sharepoint.

Do you have any idea how to do this. I am skilled in python but really never had to do something in javascript/typescript. It's sharepoint on prem.

I would appreciate your help. thank you.

I think there is a way with the SPFx framework but as I mentioned I am not experienced in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Once you generate a SPFx solution to create a webpart, follow the below steps to achieve the functionality.

1. Follow the below article to learn how to add button and trigger click  event

https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

2. Inside the handleClick function, get logged in user details using PnP JS

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/get-logged-in-user-email-name-and-id-in-sharepoint-framework-spfx-using-pnp

3. Save the details in a list

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-list-items-crud-operations-demo-using-pnpjs-in-react-based-spfx-webpa/

4. Users data can be exported from the list using export to excel option